# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to add a time interval of 1 day to a timestamp `end`, of format `0   2020-12-03 Name: Test Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]`.

`df`:

```
    Date        Id  Value
0   2020-12-03  5   050
1   2020-04-07  12  051
2   2020-05-05  6   052
3   2020-05-19  6   059
```

I used:

```
import datetime
...
end = df.loc[df.col== i, 'Date']
print(end)
start = (datetime.datetime.strptime(end,'%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
...
```

and it caught error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-d9b441080f1a> in <module>

     10     print(end)
---> 11     start = (datetime.datetime.strptime(end,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
     12 
     13 

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp
```

Comment: Pandas already parsed the date when you created the dataframe, you don't need to call `strptime()`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I removed the `strptime()`, but had another issue `TypeError: Cannot convert input [0    2020-12-02
Name: Date, dtype: object] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp` when filtering the data using the `start` and `end` dates

Comment: loc returns a series - as the error tells you, you don't want that, you want a specific element. E.g. the first in the Series, `df.loc[df.col== i, 'Date'][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, the end is in the "date" type. But it should be in str.

try this,

`end = str(end)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).